# how to show text and image into ListView from db file?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a sqlite database file that have two columns first one is the name of fruit
and second column has image of that fruit . I want to it in listView from db file . please give me solution.....

Comment: StackOverflow is not a design, coding, or tutorial service. Post the applicable code with a specific problem, and you are much more likely to get needed help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question has already been answered. So I will be just giving you some tutorials to check out:

- https://dzone.com/articles/listview-data-sqlitedatabase
- http://www.journaldev.com/9438/android-sqlite-database-example-tutorial
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3k3CunDZpFk

For the image part you can use a library like [Picasso](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149) or [Glide](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/)

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks but i don't understand the code so please give me code

Comment: I gave you all that is necessary to answer your question. Now if you don't know how to code, this is a big issue. By the way, none can give you a code and you'll just copy/paste it and it will work. You will always have to adapt the code to your needs.